# Using rowspan with array output to table in php

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I'm looking to modify a table on a page to include merged rows.

Here is the php code that deals with the output from a mysql db:

```
######## PRINT OUT TABLE WITH YEARS AND OFFICES PLUS NAMES IN CELLS ########    
for ($y = $year_max; $y >=$year_min; $y--){
    echo '<tr><th>'.$y.'</th>';

    for ($i = 0; $i<count($offices_used); $i++){

        if (isset($data[$y][$offices_used[$i]])){
            echo '<td>'.$data[$y][$offices_used[$i]].'</td>';
        } // END IF

        else {
            echo '<td></td>';
        } // END ELSE

        }   echo '</tr>';
    } // END FOR
```

The table further below is generated from a multidimensional array such as immediately below;

```
array (  

[2013] => Array
    (
        [President] => John Mills
        [Internal VP] => Virgil Bagdonas
        [External VP] => Reid Gilmore
        [Treasurer] => Todd Heino
        [Secretary] => Eric Holmquist
        [Newsletter] => Art Bodwell
        [Webmaster] => Dave Eaton
        [Photographer] => Rick Angus
        [Video Librarian] => Mike Peters
        [Store Manager] => Kevin Nee
    )

[2012] => Array
    (
        [President] => Dave Eaton
        [Internal VP] => Jim Metcalf
        [External VP] => Reid Gilmore
        [Treasurer] => Mike Peters
        [Secretary] => Eric Holmquist
        [Newsletter] => Art Bodwell
        [Webmaster] => Dave Eaton
        [Photographer] => Peter Wilcox
        [Video Librarian] => Ray Asselin
        [Store Manager] => Joe Giroux
    )

[2011] => Array
    (
        [President] => Charlie Croteau
        [Internal VP] => Reid Gilmore
        [External VP] => Rick Angus
        [Treasurer] => Mike Peters
        [Secretary] => Eric Holmquist
        [Newsletter] => Ron Rocheleau
        [Webmaster] => Dave Eaton
        [Photographer] => Peter Wilcox
        [Video Librarian] => Ray Asselin
        [Book Librarian] => Roger Boisvert
        [Store Manager] => Mike Smith
    )
```

...etc

My php code NOW generates this table from mysql db:

```
<tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>President</th>
    <th>Internal VP</th>
    <th>External VP</th>
    <th>Treasurer</th>
    <th>Secretary</th>
    <th>Webmaster</th>
    <th>Newsletter</th>
    <th>Photographer</th>
    <th>Video Librarian</th>
    <th>Book Librarian</th>
    <th>Store Manager</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>2013</th>
    <td>John Mills</td>
    <td>Virgil Bagdonas</td>
    <td>Reid Gilmore</td>
    <td>Todd Heino</td>
    <td>Eric Holmquist</td>
    <td>Dave Eaton</td>
    <td>Art Bodwell</td>
    <td>Rick Angus</td>
    <td>Mike Peters</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Kevin Nee</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>2012</th>
    <td>Dave Eaton</td>
    <td>Jim Metcalf</td>
    <td>Reid Gilmore</td>
    <td>Mike Peters</td>
    <td>Eric Holmquist</td>
    <td>Dave Eaton</td>
    <td>Art Bodwell</td>
    <td>Peter Wilcox</td>
    <td>Ray Asselin</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Joe Giroux</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>2011</th>
    <td>Charlie Croteau</td>
    <td>Reid Gilmore</td>
    <td>Rick Angus</td>
    <td>Mike Peters</td>
    <td>Eric Holmquist</td>
    <td>Dave Eaton</td>
    <td>Ron Rocheleau</td>
    <td>Peter Wilcox</td>
    <td>Ray Asselin</td>
    <td>Roger Boisvert</td>
    <td>Mike Smith</td>
</tr>
```

But I WOULD LIKE to modify the array handling output to get the following:

```
<tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>President</th>
    <th>Internal VP</th>
    <th>External VP</th>
    <th>Treasurer</th>
    <th>Secretary</th>
    <th>Webmaster</th>
    <th>Newsletter</th>
    <th>Photographer</th>
    <th>Video Librarian</th>
    <th>Book Librarian</th>
    <th>Store Manager</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>2013</th>
    <td>John Mills</td>
    <td>Virgil Bagdonas</td>
    <td rowspan= "3">Reid Gilmore</td>
    <td>Todd Heino</td>
    <td rowspan="3">Eric Holmquist</td>
    <td rowspan="9">Dave Eaton</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Art Bodwell</td>
    <td>Rick Angus</td>
    <td>Mike Peters</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Kevin Nee</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>2012</th>
    <td>Dave Eaton</td>
    <td>Jim Metcalf</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Mike Peters</td>
    <td>Peter Wilcox</td>
    <td rowspan="3">Ray Asselin</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Joe Giroux</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>2011</th>
    <td>Charlie Croteau</td>
    <td>Rick Angus</td>
    <td>Ron Rocheleau</td>
    <td>Peter Wilcox</td>
    <td>Roger Boisvert</td>
    <td>Mike Smith</td>
</tr>
```

Any leads on how to add a flag or counter to accomplish this is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean `colspan`.check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html-table/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this hope to work.(because I have not run it but think should work).

CODE for colspan:

```
for ($y = $year_max; $y >=$year_min; $y--){
    echo '<tr><th>'.$y.'</th>';

    $lastVal='';
    $buf=array();
    for ($i = 0; $i<count($offices_used); $i++){
        (!isset($data[$y][$offices_used[$i]])?($data[$y][$offices_used[$i]]=''):'');// Im not sure that is really needed

        if($lastVal==$data[$y][$offices_used[$i]]){
            $buf[count($buf)-1]['rep']++;
        }else{
            $lastVal=$data[$y][$offices_used[$i]];
            $buf[]=array('data'=>$lastVal,'rep'=>1);
        }

        foreach($buf as $arr){
            echo '<td'.($arr['rep']>1?' colspan="'.$arr['rep'].'"':'') . '>'.$arr['data'].'</td>';
        }


        }   echo '</tr>';
    } // END FOR
```

**NOTICE**: *error of code corrected*

---

CODE for rowspan:(I think it can be down easier than this. bur I have tried to be good).

```
$buf=array();
for ($i = 0; $i<count($offices_used); $i++){// this loop makes fill $buf
    $lastVal='';
    for ($y = $year_max; $y >=$year_min; $y--){
        (!isset($data[$y][$offices_used[$i]])?($data[$y][$offices_used[$i]]=''):'');// Im not sure that is really needed
        if($lastVal==$data[$y][$offices_used[$i]]){
            $buf[$i][count($buf[$i])-1]['rep']++;
        }else{
            $lastVal=$data[$y][$offices_used[$i]];
            $buf[$i][$year_max-$y]=array('data'=>$lastVal,'rep'=>1);
        }
    }
}
$mtemp=$year_max;
foreach($buf as $row){
    echo '<tr><th>'.$mtemp.'</th>';
    foreach($row as $rec){
        echo '<td'.($rec['rep']>1?' rowspan="'.$rec['rep'].'"':'') . '>'.$rec['data'].'</td>';
    }
    $mtemp--;
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

really hope to work.

**NOTICE**: *corrected*

Comment: Maybe almost but not yet. I think I grasp the concept. Thank you. Here's what I want at: http://cnew.org/cnew_officer-history-sample-merged-rows.html and what I get implementing your suggestion at: http://cnew.org/officer-history-mergerow.php

Comment: I cant open your page can you paste the HTML out put of them as jsfiddle?

Comment: this link is for which of them? new??

Comment: It is implementing what you provided.

Comment: This is what I am targeting.http://jsfiddle.net/eaton9999/xY9z9/
(never used jsfiddle before - interesting...)

Comment: oh no I think you have edited my suggestion because I have use colspan but the link you sent me has rowspan please check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html-table/info)

Comment: Sorry - Actually I assumed it was an oversight. I am looking for rowspans not colspans?? Did I miss something. Also am getting eror on line 
 (!isset($data[$y][$offices_used[$i]])?($data[$y][$offices_used[$i]]='');:'');// Im not sure that is really needed

Comment: sorry Im back and what error. and also I think I had misunderstood you so let me check things

Comment: OK so you want a very hard thing let me think

Comment: OK do you just want the rowspan or both rowspan and colspan? http://jsfiddle.net/egd8G/

Comment: Just rowspan as colspan is a different issue I have toyed with but seems much less useful. Lets stay with rowspan only. (Thanks for the help!)

Comment: your welcome. (-: OK so I will try to write it for rowspan only just need time please check every 15 min.

Comment: btw @eaton9999 the new user let me tell you somthing.here is a site in a simple Q and A form and if you want to get answer of a hard question or a long question you should set bounty point for that maybe 100.(-: but I just did it because I enjoy that.and all I am expecting you is to be a good supporter (accept and/or vote my and others answers and comments).(-:

Comment: Tried latest but no go. See http://jsfiddle.net/eaton9999/tSFhP/
Will check back 6pm EST. Thanks again.

Also - I see great advantage on being an active member in this site. Will vote and do what I can to support it. Thanks for mentioning your advice. thought rowspan issue easier but will look into what bounty is.

Comment: please write the errors you get and also edited. and also think checking this would help you get things. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using:

```
############################################################################
######## PRINT OUT TABLE WITH YEARS AND OFFICES PLUS NAMES IN CELLS ########    
for ($y = $year_max; $y >=$year_min; $y--){ // Loop through years
    echo '<tr><th>'.$y.'</th>';

    for ($i = 0; $i<count($offices_used); $i++){

        if (isset($data[$y][$offices_used[$i]])){

            $rowz =1;


            if(!($data[$y][$offices_used[$i]] == $data[($y+1)][$offices_used[$i]])){

                while ($data[$y][$offices_used[$i]] == $data[($y-$rowz)][$offices_used[$i]]) $rowz ++; 
                echo '<td rowspan = "'.$rowz.'">'.$data[$y][$offices_used[$i]].'</td>';
            }

        } // END IF

        else {
            echo '<td align = "center"> - </td>';
        } // END ELSE

        }   echo '</tr>';  // End row of current year

} // END FOR Loop through years 
echo '</table>';
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/eaton9999/8gMVK/ for resultant output page.

Thanks again to imsiso and other who helped!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library a few days ago that can handle this stuff..
Have a look at https://github.com/donquixote/cellbrush

The benefit of the library is that you don't need to think about the order of cells in html, and which cells need to be skipped due to rowspan or colspan. Instead, you can just "paint" a cell anywhere in the grid, with whichever rowspan or colspan you want. And instead of specifying a number for rowspan or colspan, you simply specify the first and last row and column names of the rospan/colspan region.

E.g.

```
$table->td(['2011', '2013'], 'Secretary', 'Eric Holmquist');
```

Below is some code that creates the table you were asking for, with the help of this library. You still need some logic to calculate the intervals, but at least you don't need to worry about the integrity of the table html.

(This question is quite old, but there might still be people running into it from Google. So I hope it might be useful.)

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$data = array(
  '2013' => array(
    'President' => 'John Mills',
    'Internal VP' => 'Virgil Bagdonas',
    'External VP' => 'Reid Gilmore',
    'Treasurer' => 'Todd Heino',
    'Secretary' => 'Eric Holmquist',
    'Newsletter' => 'Art Bodwell',
    'Webmaster' => 'Dave Eaton',
    'Photographer' => 'Rick Angus',
    'Video Librarian' => 'Mike Peters',
    'Store Manager' => 'Kevin Nee',
  ),
  '2012' => array(
    'President' => 'Dave Eaton',
    'Internal VP' => 'Jim Metcalf',
    'External VP' => 'Reid Gilmore',
    'Treasurer' => 'Mike Peters',
    'Secretary' => 'Eric Holmquist',
    'Newsletter' => 'Art Bodwell',
    'Webmaster' => 'Dave Eaton',
    'Photographer' => 'Peter Wilcox',
    'Video Librarian' => 'Ray Asselin',
    'Store Manager' => 'Joe Giroux',
  ),
  '2011' => array(
    'President' => 'Charlie Croteau',
    'Internal VP' => 'Reid Gilmore',
    'External VP' => 'Rick Angus',
    'Treasurer' => 'Mike Peters',
    'Secretary' => 'Eric Holmquist',
    'Newsletter' => 'Ron Rocheleau',
    'Webmaster' => 'Dave Eaton',
    'Photographer' => 'Peter Wilcox',
    'Video Librarian' => 'Ray Asselin',
    'Book Librarian' => 'Roger Boisvert',
    'Store Manager' => 'Mike Smith',
  ),
);

// Collect positions to build table columns.
$positions = [];
foreach ($data as $year => $yearData) {
  foreach ($yearData as $position => $person) {
    $positions[$position] = TRUE;
  }
}
$positions = array_keys($positions);

// Define table columns.
$table = (new \Donquixote\Cellbrush\Table())
  ->addColName('year')
  ->addColNames($positions)
;

// Create thead section.
$headRow = $table->thead()->addRow('head');
$headRow->th('year', 'Year');
foreach ($positions as $position) {
  $headRow->th($position, $position);
}

// Create table rows with labels based on year.
$years = array_keys($data);
$table->addRowNames($years);
foreach ($years as $year) {
  $table->th($year, 'year', $year);
}

// Fill table cells in each column.
foreach ($positions as $position) {
  $periodPerson = NULL;
  $periodFirstYear = NULL;
  $periodLastYear = NULL;
  $column = $table->colHandle($position);
  foreach ($years as $year) {
    $person = isset($data[$year][$position])
      ? $data[$year][$position]
      : '-';
    if (!isset($periodFirstYear)) {
      // First year.
      $periodFirstYear = $year;
    }
    elseif ($person !== $periodPerson) {
      // Add a table cell with rowspan.
      $column->td([$periodFirstYear, $periodLastYear], $periodPerson);
      $periodFirstYear = $year;
    }
    $periodPerson = $person;
    $periodLastYear = $year;
  }
  if (isset($periodFirstYear)) {
    // Add a table cell with rowspan.
    $column->td([$periodFirstYear, $periodLastYear], $periodPerson);
  }
}

print $table->render();
```